# jQuery close and open only one element at once

Tags: jquery, html, slide

Before going into my problem, I will post reference where I found partial solution:

- [Here is the answer to my similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656941/jquery-toggle-close-all-except-this/4657463#4657463)

Now first I will post my whole example on jsFiddle, stripped down of unnecessary stuff:

- [My example](http://jsfiddle.net/exwSP/)

I will also post the code here:

- HTML:

---

```
<ol class="decimalListFirstOl">
<li class="decimalListLi">
    Test1
    <ol class="decimalListSecondOl">
         <li class="columns decimalListLi">
            Test1<span class="show">+</span>
            <div class="hide">
                <ul class="defaultFont">
                    <li>Test1</li>
                    <li>Test2</li>
                    <li>...</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="columns decimalListLi">
            Test2
            <span class="show">+</span>
            <div class="hide">
                <ul class="defaultFont">
                    <li>Test1</li>
                    <li>Test2</li>
                    <li>...</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="columns decimalListLi">
            Test3
            <span class="show">+</span>
            <div class="hide">
                <ul class="defaultFont">
                    <li>Test1</li>
                    <li>Test2</li>
                    <li>...</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

- CSS:

---

```
.hide {
display: none;
}
.columns {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.decimalListLi {
    color: #627490;
    display: block;
}
.decimalListLi:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    counter-increment: item;
}
.decimalListFirstOl {
    counter-reset: item;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.decimalListSecondOl {
    counter-reset: item;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.defaultFont {
    color: #525252;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

- JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY:

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('.hide').eq(index).slideToggle("slow").siblings('.hide').hide();
    });
});
```

I am using jQuery 1.6.2. I want that one click on the sign(+), closes currently opened column and the clicked column opens (slides down). I have already achieved the opening and closing, but for some reason it always opens and closes the first column, no matter which + is clicked. Now I have followed the answer on first link, but the problem is, I have nested ol and li and that's why probably this line of code:

```
var index = $(this).index();
```

for some reason always returns 0! Which means it will always open and close the first column.

Comment: When you do `$(this).index()`, you're creating a new jQuery object with only a single element: whichever span was clicked. That's why `index()` always returns 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your toggle buttons are index '0' cause their `.index()` is referenced to *'index of element **in** parent'* And there's only **1** '.show' inside 'his' `li` parent.

So just look for the **parent** index() using

```
 var index = $(this).parent().index();
```

AND HERE IS A DEMO TO TOGGLE ALREADY OPENED MENUS:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/exwSP/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        $('.hide').hide();
        $('.hide').eq(index).slideToggle("slow");      
    });
});
```

You can use this solution too  ( using **`.next('.hide')`** It will look for the next element .hide) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show').click(function() {
        $('.hide').hide();
        $(this).next('.hide').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: How he fixed it: changed `$(this).index()` to `$(this).parent().index()`

Comment: That opens and closes the right one, but it does not close the other ones, that are already opened.

Comment: Will accept your answer for nice formatting :), despite that the solution from @Dennis also works ok.

Comment: @Jernej roXon's example will always open a menu, even if it's already opened.  Mine will hide an open menu.  I'm not sure which behavior you find desirable, just thought you should be aware of that difference.

Comment: @Dennis yeah I should have written in op, that that behavior is desirable. Again, thanks for your answer. I upvoted it, also I think it will come in handy one day.

Answer (score 1):

siblings() will only get elements that have the same parent.

```
var target = $(this).siblings(".hide"); //Get the div that corresponds to the plus we just clicked.
$(".hide").not(target).hide(); //Hide hidable elements that are not the target
target.slideToggle();          //Toggle the targetted div
```

Answer (score 0):

You should switch over to the `each()` method to set up your event.

```
$('.show').each(function(index)
{
    var closureReference = index;
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        $('.hide').eq(closureReference).slideToggle("slow").siblings('.hide').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: That opens and closes the right one, but it does not close the other ones, that are already opened.