# Jquery accordion effect

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a problem with a jquery function. My HTML looks like this, I have several elements like the one below.

```
<div id="design">
 <span class="flyout_hover">click me
  <div class="flyout">
   show me 1
  </div>
 </span>
</div>

<div id="seo">
 <span class="flyout_hover">click me
  <div class="flyout">
   show me 2
  </div>
 </span>
</div>

<div id="mobil">
 <span class="flyout_hover">click me
  <div class="flyout">
   show me 3
  </div>
 </span>
</div>
```

EDIT: I have added a new div around each element.

Then I have used this jquery code, which I found here: [jQuery toggle - Close all except this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656941/jquery-toggle-close-all-except-this/4657070#4657070)

```
$(".flyout_hover").click(function() {
   var index = $(this).index();
    $('.flyout').eq(index).toggle().siblings('.flyout').hide();
});
```

I want to have the same effect as in the example above, like an accordion. But when I click on <.flyout_hover> only the <.flyout> inside the last <.flyout_hover> is shown, no matter what <.flyout_hover> I click.

I guess it has something to do with the index thingy, but I have a hard time finding a solution to it.

Best regards

Vegar

Comment: Do you mean somthing like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4Wwnm/31/ ? cheers!

Comment: Yeah, something like that. But I only want the div.flyout to open/close when you click the span.flyout_hover. If a div.flyout is allready open I want it to close if you click on another span.flyout_hover and at the same time the div.flyout inside the span.flyout_hover you justs clicked to open. If you know what I mean.. lot of flyouts here..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".flyout_hover").click(function() {
   var index = $(this).index();
   $('.flyout').eq(index).toggle();
   $(this).siblings().children('.flyout').hide();
});
```

EDIT: This is because the .flyout has no siblings inside the containing .flyout_hover element.  You have to find the siblings of .flyout_hover and then hide their children.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3GXk6/5/

Also, maybe you want to use divs instead of span for .flyout_hover elements?

EDIT 2: If you only always have one .flyout div inside its parent, you don't need the index and then you can just use this:

```
$(".flyout_hover").click(function() {
   $('.flyout', this).toggle();
   $(this).siblings().children('.flyout').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e72hk/

EDIT 3: When you wrap them in divs as in your edited HTML code, you can just do this instead:

```
$(".flyout_hover").click(function() {
    $('.flyout', this).toggle();
    $(this).parent('div').siblings('div').find('.flyout').hide();    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e72hk/15/

Comment: I have gotten this to work if I set it up exactly like you have (and i should), but I didnt take into account that each of the before mentioned elements (.flyout_hover and .flyout) is inside another div. This is somehow f...ing up the code. If I open a .flyout this will stay open when I clik on another .flyout_hover. I didnt think this would matter, since all the elements are somehow wrapped inside something else.. like <body> and <wrapper> and so on.. I have updated the html in the example. Sorry for the inconvenience.. :/

Comment: I gave up, found it was easyer to tweak my html than banging my head agains the jquerywall.. thanks to all for helping!

Comment: @Vegar: Sorry, I didn't notice your previous comment until now... can fix this I think by using the siblings of the parent of the clicked .flyout_hover - but if you are moving on I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @VegarvonVallestad: I know you moved on, but I updated my answer with a solution to your edits.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, really appreciate your help on this one! I have not tested the code, but it looks sweet in jsfiddle, will try to implement it later! Sadly I`m not very good at javascript, so even small problems throws me of my horse..:) thanks again!

Comment: @VegarvonVallestad: You're welcome - just remember that jQuery is normally VERY dependant on the HTML structure = so it makes kind of sense to sort out your HTML first. Also, jQuery looks intimidating at first sight, but most of it is actually exceedingly simple to grasp - it will definitely pay off to work through a basic tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will do that!

Answer (score 0):

Your html code suppose to look like this. Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3GXk6/)

```
<div class="flyout_hover">Div first </div>
<div class="flyout_hover">Div second</div>
<div class="flyout">Menu1 </div>
<div class="flyout">Menu2 </div>

.container {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but is there a way to achieve the same effect when I have the html like I have arranged it?

Comment: can u update your html code, at least with 2 divs so I can update jquery. At the moment I don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have updatet my html code in the example over, my problem is that no matter what span.flyout_hover I click, only the div.flyout inside the last span.flyout_hover get shown.