# Expand/Collapse parent elements using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pardon my limited js experience. I have inherited some old, frameset-based software online documentation that I need to update to HTML5/responsive. The writers input each "topic" into a desktop-based CMS and then the CMS 'publishes' each topic to an html page. Along with the topic pages, it publishes a table-of-contents.htm (TOC) that I load in and use to enable the user to select and load the desired topic.

Topics are grouped by "books" or parent topics, resulting in a tree-like TOC. By default, all "books" are collapsed. I need to be able to expand/collapse TOC entries so that when the user selects a topic, that topic and it's direct parent topic is expanded. Here is a subset of the toc.htm that the system generates for me. I have no control over this generated file:

```html
<!-- excerpt from generated Table Of Contents -->

<h1 class="heading1">Contents</h1>
<table class="tabledhtmltoc" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="toc">&nbsp;<br>
   <img id="p145054" src="plus.gif" onclick="exp('145054')" alt=""><img id="b145054" src="cbook.gif" alt=""><a id="a145054" href="145054.htm">Data Optimization Online Help</a><br>
   <span id="s145054" class="sp"><img style="margin-left:16px" id="p90584" src="plus.gif" onclick="exp('90584')" alt=""><img id="b90584" src="cbook.gif" alt=""><a id="a90584" href="xxoxxrview.htm">Corporate Enterprise oxxrview</a><br>
   <span id="s90584" class="sp"><img style="margin-left:32px" src="space.gif" alt=""><img src="topic.gif" alt=""><a id="a98605" href="98605.htm">The Home page - Corporate Enterprise</a><br>
    <img style="margin-left:32px" src="space.gif" alt=""><img src="topic.gif" alt=""><a id="a84599" href="logging_on_xx.htm">Logging on to the Corporate Enterprise Home page</a><br>
    <img style="margin-left:32px" src="space.gif" alt=""><img src="topic.gif" alt=""><a id="a134150" href="134150.htm">Logging off of Corporate Enterprise</a><br>
    <img style="margin-left:32px" src="space.gif" alt=""><img src="topic.gif" alt=""><a id="a100102" href="accessing_xx_solutions.htm">Accessing a Corporate Enterprise application</a><br>
   </span>
      <img style="margin-left:16px" id="p144468" src="plus.gif" onclick="exp('144468')" alt=""><img id="b144468" src="cbook.gif" alt=""><a id="a144468" href="144468.htm">About the System user interface</a>
      <br>
      <span id="s144468" class="sp"><img style="margin-left:32px" src="space.gif" alt=""><img src="topic.gif" alt=""><a id="a142049" href="142049.htm">Drawers</a><br>
    <img style="margin-left:32px" src="space.gif" alt=""><img src="topic.gif" alt=""><a id="a142437" href="142437.htm">View columns</a><br>
    <img style="margin-left:32px" src="space.gif" alt=""><img src="topic.gif" alt=""><a id="a143110" href="143110.htm">Filter values in columns</a><br>
    <img style="margin-left:32px" id="p143373" src="plus.gif" onclick="exp('143373')" alt=""><img id="b143373" src="cbook.gif" alt=""><a id="a143373" href="usinghelp_xx.htm">Using the online help</a><br>
   <span id="s143373" class="sp"><img style="margin-left:48px" src="space.gif" alt=""><img src="topic.gif" alt=""><a id="a143352" href="accessing_help_xx.htm">Accessing help</a><br>
    <img style="margin-left:48px" src="space.gif" alt=""><img src="topic.gif" alt=""><a id="a143353" href="finding_topics_with_contents.htm">Finding topics with Contents</a><br>
    <img style="margin-left:48px" src="space.gif" alt=""><img src="topic.gif" alt=""><a id="a143354" href="finding_topics_with_search.htm">Finding topics with Search</a><br>
    </span></span>

      <!-- entries continue on for depending on how many topics/nodes there are in total -->

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In each individual topic page there is an onload that references the id's of the topic and it's parent:

```html
<body  onload="if (isTOCLoaded()) {expand('144468');expand('145054');highlight('142049')}">
```

I have jquery and prefer to use it, as I'm using it for many other functions in this project, but am fine to use vanilla javascript if it makes more sense.

How would I go about writing a function like this:

```html
function expand(id) { // this is called for each id via the body onload
    // expand the id (topic) in the toc...
}
```

Any help is GREATLY appreciated! I've spent hours on this : (

Comment: Is there a live example?

Comment: Here you go - thanks! http://help.mark2741.webfactional.com/042118-1000/134150.htm

Comment: So we want to toggle the menu tree on the left?

Comment: [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)?

Comment: Not just toggle everything expand/collapse - I was able to figure that out (by simply setting the display to none for the 'sp' class). What I need to do is: when the user clicks on a link in the menu tree, the page loads on the right and then the entire tree is collapsed EXCEPT for the loaded topic and it's parent topic (and all siblings).

Comment: [This is how to close everything apart from clicked item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656941/jquery-toggle-close-all-except-this) and for the other part of the click, you need to do an ajax call

Comment: thanks @Pete - I'm not totally understanding it on first glance, but will explore further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next code will solve what you are looking for. The idea is to run when the page loads

This is the sequence.

1. Close all items as if nothing is selected
2. Obtain the selected item via the url
3. Go through the parents opening the items.

A lot of jquery and targets to do this. It could have cases where it does work, but I didnt encounter any.

Hope this helps :)

```
  //Reset tree to all close
    $('.sp').css('display','none');
    $('img[src="obook.gif"]').attr('src','cbook.gif');
    $('img[src="minus.gif"]').attr('src','plus.gif');

    //Get selected via url
    var selectedUrl = window.location.pathname.split('.')[0].split('/')[2];
    var selectedItem = $('a[href="'+selectedUrl+'.htm"]');

    var checkParent = selectedItem;
    //Iterate on parents an open all elements
    while($(checkParent).parent().hasClass('sp')==true){
        checkParent = $(checkParent).parent();
        $(checkParent).css('display','block');
        var newId = $(checkParent).attr('id').substr(1);
        $('#b'+newId).attr('src','obook.gif');
        $('#p'+newId).attr('src','minus.gif');
    };
```

Comment: @user172586 Can you add a console.log to see if that place is working

Comment: @user172586 where did you add it?

Comment: @user172586 You add it to the head. The code is running before the page loads. Add a ``.load()`` listener

Comment: @user172586 What is the jsfiddle for?

Comment: Sorry. I made sure the code you provided is running - it is in an init() that is run on window load, after the toc is loaded. I verified with console.log. I've isolated the problem - what is happening is that this line: while($(checkParent).parent().hasClass('sp')==true)  never evaluates to true. I think the problem/difficulty is that the DOM isn't hierarchical - to simulate a true 'tree' the original developer just set the margin-left to indent each tree node. @Gerardo BLANCO

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! Thank you so much! Not sure what happened but I just published and uploaded a fresh copy to the server and tested and it's working! Thank you so much! @Gerardo BLANCO